# Is it possible to use AudioFileWritePackets to write to a file without replacing existing data on that file?

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-audio

My code is based off of the code in Chapter 6 of Learning Core Audio.

This function is designed to take an input file and copy the packets form that file to an output file. I am using it to write the data of many input files onto one output file, and it works quite well.

The only problem I am having is when I add a new input file and set the startPacketPosition to an area on the output file that already has packets written to it. It replaces the old data with the new data.

Is there a way to write new packets to a file without replacing the existing data. It would be like adding a sound effect to a song file without replacing any of the song data.

If this isn't possible to do using AudioFileWritePackets, what would be the best alternative?

```
static void writeInputFileToOutputFile(AudioStreamBasicDescription *format, ExtAudioFileRef *inputFile, AudioFileID *outputFile, UInt32 *startPacketPosition) {
    //determine the size of the output buffer
    UInt32 outputBufferSize = 32 * 1024; //32kb
    UInt32 sizePerPacket = format->mBytesPerPacket;
    UInt32 packetsPerBuffer = outputBufferSize / sizePerPacket;

    //allocate a buffer for recieving the data
    UInt8 *outputBuffer = (UInt8 *)malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * outputBufferSize);

    //read-convert-write
    while (1) {
        AudioBufferList convertedData; //create an audio buffer list
        convertedData.mNumberBuffers = 1; //with only one buffer
        //set the properties on the single buffer
        convertedData.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = format->mChannelsPerFrame;
        convertedData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = outputBufferSize;
        convertedData.mBuffers[0].mData = outputBuffer;

        //get the number of frames and buffer data from the input file
        UInt32 framesPerBuffer = packetsPerBuffer;
        CheckError(ExtAudioFileRead(*inputFile, &framesPerBuffer, &convertedData), "ExtAudioFileRead");

        //if framecount is 0, were finished
        if (framesPerBuffer == 0) {
            return;
        }

        UInt32 bytes = format->mBytesPerPacket;
        CheckError(AudioFileWritePackets(*outputFile, false, framesPerBuffer*bytes, NULL, *startPacketPosition, &framesPerBuffer, convertedData.mBuffers[0].mData), "AudioFileWritePackets");

        //increase the ouput file packet position
        *startPacketPosition += framesPerBuffer;
    }
    free(outputBuffer);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to accomplish this using AVMutableComposition

```
-(void)addInputAsset:(AVURLAsset *)input toOutputComposition:(AVMutableComposition *)composition atTime:(float)seconds {
    //add the input to the composition
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[input tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

    //set the start time
    int sampleRate = 44100;
    CMTime nextClipStartTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, sampleRate);
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, input.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
}
```

To use this method to mix two audio files you would call it like this:

```
-(void)mixAudio {
    //create a mutable compsition
    AVMutableComposition* composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    //audio file 1
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"path/to/file1.mp3"];
    AVURLAsset* asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url1 options:nil];
    [self addInputAsset:asset1 toOutputComposition:composition atTime:0.0];

    //audio file 2
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"path/to/file2.aif"];
    AVURLAsset* asset2 = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url2 options:nil];
    [self addInputAsset:asset2 toOutputComposition:composition atTime:0.2];

    //create the export session
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    if (exportSession == nil) {
        //ERROR: abort
    }

    // configure export session  output with all our parameters
    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"path/to/output_file.m4a"]; // output path
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A; // output file type

    //export the file
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status) {
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
        } else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status) {
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Export Session Status: %ld", (long)exportSession.status);
        }
    }];
}
```